# Undefined method 'reject' when using mongoid-paperclip gem

Tags: mongoid, paperclip

The error I am getting

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `reject' for #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fab6ea5c370>):
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:3:in `create'
```

The form (it's in HAML)

```
  %form{:id => 'photo-upload-form', :method => 'post', :action => '/photos', :enctype => 'multipart/form-data'}
    %input{:type => 'file', :id => 'photo', :name => 'photo'}
    %input.btn{:type => 'submit', :value => 'Upload Photo'}
```

photos_controller.rb Controller

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController
  def create # POST /photos
    photo = Photo.create(params[:photo])
    render :nothing => true
  end
end
```

photo.rb Model

```
class Photo
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paperclip

  has_mongoid_attached_file :photo,
                            :storage => :s3,
                            :bucket => '<My_Bucket>',
                            :s3_credentials => {
                                :access_key_id => '<My_Access_Key>',
                                :secret_access_key => '<My_Secret_Access_Key>'
                            },
                            :styles => {
                                :thumb  => "100x100",
                                :medium => "200x200",
                                :large => "600x400"
                            }
end
```

Gemfile (have run bundle install)

```
gem 'mongoid-paperclip', :require => "mongoid_paperclip"
gem 'aws-sdk'
```

Versions

```
Ruby 1.9.3
Rails 3.2.3
Mongoid 2.4.8
Mongoid-Paperclip 0.0.7
Paperclip 3.1.2
aws-sdk 1.5.7
```

The code is fairly simple and I've followed the docs. No idea what I should do.

Answer (score 1):

So, the issue was

```
    photo = Photo.create(params[:photo])
```

should have been

```
    photo = Photo.create(params)
```

Now, I hope you'll excuse me as I go and kick myself. :)